# Creating a "visitor is new" rule

Tags: personalization

I want to create a basic rule for new visitors to my site. I've started with `where the visitor identification is equal to the specific value` but what is the specific value for new visitors?

**OR**

should the rule be based upon some other condition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for the condition `where the visit no. compares to number`.

[image]

This condition will compare the number of visits detected for the current user with a number of your choice.

E.g. to detect new visitor you can set this as equal to 1, or smaller than 2, .. or whatever suits your business logic.

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you!